# How do you let your boom op monitor audio

Tags: boom, monitoring

I am just wondering for those of you who regually use boom ops your favoured methods of letting them monitor the audio being recorded. Some I have worked with use their own mixers or mix pre d etc but lots seem to prefer wireless methods or simple wired set ups?

Answer (score 3):

Wireless is the way to go.  Try feeding the boom op what's coming out of the mains via a Comtek feed.  Have your boom op transmit via a Lectro setup.  That way the boom up is fully unrestrained by cable tethers.  I boom op'd on a feature a long time ago and the mixer preferring working this way - it was fantastic, freedom for both the mixer and boom op to be able to do their jobs best.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a boom and i absolutely hate comteks!! Terrible terrible sound....I've been using the sennheiser EK 2000 and like it much better! Longer range and much better sound.

If we don't have a wireless transmitter for the boom mic, i prefer using a duplex cable, and have the monitoring trough the cable as well.

Comment: I should add that we also have walkie talkies so that the mixer can talk to me if i'm not "plugged in"

Answer (score 1):

I can't afford a Comtek feed yet, but wireless feed with Sennheiser G3s works a treat in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Rolls PM55 for the boom op usually. Allows them to monitor easily with their own volume control.